# How can you fill svg's in javascipt with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, svg, button

Is there a way to fill SVG images with Javascript code, for example if you had a button with an id of `myButton` and you had a SVG inside it and used the `document.getElementById("myButton").style` to fill in the SVG, how could you do it? This is the code I tried:

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").style.svg.fill="yellow";
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="submit">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M281.1,0c-127.318,0-230.9,103.582-230.9,230.9c0,45.12,13.019,87.25,35.483,122.853l-70.654,70.654
          c-20.039,20.039-20.039,52.527,0,72.564c20.039,20.039,52.527,20.039,72.564,0l70.654-70.654
          c35.605,22.464,77.735,35.483,122.853,35.483c127.318,0,230.9-103.582,230.9-230.9S408.42,0,281.1,0z M281.1,410.489
          c-99.025,0-179.589-80.564-179.589-179.589S182.074,51.311,281.1,51.311S460.689,131.875,460.689,230.9
          S380.127,410.489,281.1,410.489z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the SVG element and set the `fill` style.

```js
let svg = document.getElementById("myButton").getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
svg.style.fill = "yellow";
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="submit">
   <svg width="32px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M281.1,0c-127.318,0-230.9,103.582-230.9,230.9c0,45.12,13.019,87.25,35.483,122.853l-70.654,70.654
          c-20.039,20.039-20.039,52.527,0,72.564c20.039,20.039,52.527,20.039,72.564,0l70.654-70.654
          c35.605,22.464,77.735,35.483,122.853,35.483c127.318,0,230.9-103.582,230.9-230.9S408.42,0,281.1,0z M281.1,410.489
          c-99.025,0-179.589-80.564-179.589-179.589S182.074,51.311,281.1,51.311S460.689,131.875,460.689,230.9
          S380.127,410.489,281.1,410.489z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("Layer_1").style.fill="yellow";
```

you must target the svg element not the parent div.and write it like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myButton').querySelector('svg').style.fill = 'yellow';
```

Or you can eliminate the call to getElementById

```
document.querySelector('#myButton  svg').style.fill = 'yellow';
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the color is assigned by clicking on the button. And you had a mistake - instead of `style.svg.fill`, you need to write `style.fill`.

```js
var button_svg = document.querySelector("#myButton");

button_svg.onclick = function (){
   this.style.fill="yellow";
}
```

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="submit">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M281.1,0c-127.318,0-230.9,103.582-230.9,230.9c0,45.12,13.019,87.25,35.483,122.853l-70.654,70.654
          c-20.039,20.039-20.039,52.527,0,72.564c20.039,20.039,52.527,20.039,72.564,0l70.654-70.654
          c35.605,22.464,77.735,35.483,122.853,35.483c127.318,0,230.9-103.582,230.9-230.9S408.42,0,281.1,0z M281.1,410.489
          c-99.025,0-179.589-80.564-179.589-179.589S182.074,51.311,281.1,51.311S460.689,131.875,460.689,230.9
          S380.127,410.489,281.1,410.489z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

It's toggle.

```js
var button_svg = document.querySelector("#myButton");

button_svg.onclick = function (){
   this.classList.toggle('svg_yellow');;
}
```

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
}

.svg_yellow {
    fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="submit">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M281.1,0c-127.318,0-230.9,103.582-230.9,230.9c0,45.12,13.019,87.25,35.483,122.853l-70.654,70.654
          c-20.039,20.039-20.039,52.527,0,72.564c20.039,20.039,52.527,20.039,72.564,0l70.654-70.654
          c35.605,22.464,77.735,35.483,122.853,35.483c127.318,0,230.9-103.582,230.9-230.9S408.42,0,281.1,0z M281.1,410.489
          c-99.025,0-179.589-80.564-179.589-179.589S182.074,51.311,281.1,51.311S460.689,131.875,460.689,230.9
          S380.127,410.489,281.1,410.489z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

It's no click.

```js
document.querySelector("#myButton").style.fill="yellow";
```

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="submit">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M281.1,0c-127.318,0-230.9,103.582-230.9,230.9c0,45.12,13.019,87.25,35.483,122.853l-70.654,70.654
          c-20.039,20.039-20.039,52.527,0,72.564c20.039,20.039,52.527,20.039,72.564,0l70.654-70.654
          c35.605,22.464,77.735,35.483,122.853,35.483c127.318,0,230.9-103.582,230.9-230.9S408.42,0,281.1,0z M281.1,410.489
          c-99.025,0-179.589-80.564-179.589-179.589S182.074,51.311,281.1,51.311S460.689,131.875,460.689,230.9
          S380.127,410.489,281.1,410.489z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```